# javascript scrollIntoView function does not work inside my global event listener

Tags: javascript

I'm using scrollIntoView to scroll after creating form dynamically with javascript. Using the same way on chrome console works fine but when used inside my event method it does nothing. can you help me why?

html form to copy

```
<div id="comment_form_template">
        <div class="row shadow mx-1 my-2 border rounded border-secondary bg-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row p-1 bg-info rounded-top" id="comment_form_title_color">
                    <h6 class="my-auto text-white font-weight-bold "><small>comment</small></h6>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <form action="#" method="POST" class="col-12 mt-1 px-1">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{ comment_form.comment | append_attr:"class:col-12" | attr:"style:font-size:12px; height:85px; resize:none;" }}
                        <button type="submit" class="mb-1 float-right btn btn-info btn-sm px-1 py-0">
                            <small>submit comment</small>
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
window.onload = () => {
    var form_template = document.getElementById('comment_form_template');
    var test = form_template.cloneNode(true);
    test_form = test.querySelector("#comment_form_title_color")
    test_form.setAttribute("class", "row p-1 bg-warning rounded-top");
    test_form.firstElementChild.setAttribute("class", "my-auto text-dark font-weight-bold ")


    document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        var t = e.target.id.split("_")[1]
        if (e.target.id.split("_")[0] === "node" ) {
            var target_div = document.getElementById(`hiddenInput_${t}`)
            var target_div_isForm = target_div.getAttribute("data-isForm")
            if (target_div_isForm === "False"){
                target_div.innerHTML = test.innerHTML
                target_div.setAttribute("data-isForm", "True")
            } else if (target_div_isForm === "True"){
                target_div.innerHTML = ""
                target_div.setAttribute("data-isForm", "False")
            }
        }
        e.target.scrollIntoView()
        // target_div.scrollIntoView() doesn't work as well
    })

};
```

element which i want my screen to move

```
<div id="hiddenInput_{{node.pk}}" data-isForm="False"></div>
```

element that i click to make a form

```
<div class="row d-inline-flex float-right mr-1">  
      <a href="#"><small class="ml-2 text-dark"><strong>subComment</strong></small></a>       
</div>
```

by the way the form creates fine but the problem is that after creating the form screen scrolls up to top of the page

Comment: `e.target` is in this case always the element that you have clicked on. So you are telling the browser to scroll to that element on which you have clicked.

Comment: What is it that you click on to get to the correct form? Could you add some relevent *rendered* html for us to see how your page works. What is the `scroll_into` function? And where is your cloned form added to the page?

Comment: sorry the scroll_info function was a function to debug myself. the problem is that the browser doesn't scroll to the element that i clicked but scrolls way up to the top after clicking the element

Comment: So, what kind of element do you click on?

Comment: Thank you for asking that........ the problem was on the button that i was clicking to create a from . the href='#' was scrolling the screen up to the top.... Thx ! ..